# Is access to a static function variable slower than access to a global variable?

Tags: c++, static, global-variables

[Static local variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) are initialised on the first function call:

> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier static have static storage duration but are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration (unless their initialization is zero- or constant-initialization, which can be performed before the block is first entered). On all further calls, the declaration is skipped.

Also, in C++11 there are even more checks:

> If multiple threads attempt to initialize the same static local variable concurrently, the initialization occurs exactly once (similar behavior can be obtained for arbitrary functions with std::call_once).
>   Note: usual implementations of this feature use variants of the double-checked locking pattern, which reduces runtime overhead for already-initialized local statics to a single non-atomic boolean comparison.   (since C++11)

At the same time, [global variables seem to be initialised on program start](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration) (though technically only *allocation*/*deallocation* is mentioned on cppreference):

> static storage duration. The storage for the object is allocated when the program begins and deallocated when the program ends. Only one instance of the object exists. All objects declared at namespace scope (including global namespace) have this storage duration, plus those declared with static or extern.

So given the following example:

```
struct A {
    // complex type...
};
const A& f()
{
    static A local{};
    return local;
}

A global{};
const A& g()
{
    return global;
}
```

am I correct to assume that `f()` has to check whether its variable was initialised every time it is called and thus `f()` will be slower than `g()`?

Comment: All correct. If you want to avoid the repeated check, you can use a schwartz counter: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter

Comment: I think this is the proposal, you can find a discussion of the performance impact (one extra load, one extra cache hit on a thread local) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2660.htm

Comment: I want to add, that with the static local you are a bit "safer" because you have a guaranteed constructed object when accessing it via the function f(). this is not necessarily the case with the global object (with or without the nifty/schwarz counter). If another global object wants to access your `A global` and its initialized before your global, than you may run into hard to find errors.

Comment: @phön, as far as I understand consistent use of nifty counter solves initialisation order problem for global variables.

Comment: @DevNull Its purpose is to guard, but you can still run into a problem: https://wandbox.org/permlink/BMdadbrGDyr4rnAI In this example Bar shall be guarded by the niffty counter. Bar holds an integer. In Bars ctor we set it to 42. Since all global static memory gets cleared to zero in the start, the integer will hold zero before the bar ctor was executed. Foo is a class which uses bar, but does not include bar in its own header. In src1.cpp i added a global static Foo. Its not defined which cpp file gets "executed" first, so its src1.cpp vs bar.cpp. When bar.cpp was first, all fine...

Comment: @DevNull ...if src1.cpp was first, we read the zero. You can experiment with the cpp order on the left (it seems the order is equivalent to the order in the programm). If you do this with the iostream header, you get a segfault (this is why i added the include iostreams everywhere). If you comment out the `#define niffty` in Foo.cpp you can see the result when ussing static function objects

Comment: @phön you need to `#include "Bar.h"` from `Foo.h` (or even in `src1.cpp`) , then this example will work correctly.

Comment: @DevNull I know. But why would i do that? I dont need any functionality from Bar in my Foo.h. Maybe i dont even know which functionality the functions in the Foo class use. And so we have this "fiasco".

Comment: that's why I said  "consistent" use of nifty counters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198322/is-access-to-a-static-function-variable-slower-than-access-to-a-global-variable?noredirect=1#comment91558798_52198322

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are conceptually correct of course, but contemporary architectures can deal with this.

A modern compiler and architecture would arrange the pipeline such that the already-initialised branch was assumed. The overhead of initialisation would therefore incur an extra pipeline dump, that's all.

If you're in any doubt, check the assembly.

Comment: Exemplary assembly: https://godbolt.org/z/iK5V-b. Note the `movzx eax, BYTE PTR guard variable for f()::x[rip]` instruction and the following check performed each time the function is invoked.

Comment: @DanielLangr - One should also note the `jne .L12` which means the bulk of the initialization will only be performed once, even with a basic branch predictor.

Comment: @StoryTeller why do you have to mention branch predictor? The initialization will be performed once even without any predictor.

Comment: @Ruslan - Yes. The point was to support Bathsheba's point. Even a basic predictor will only pay the major cost (filling the instruction pipeline and then dumping it) once. With no predictor it's unlikely to even try and keep loading instructions into any pipeline, innit?

Comment: And in theory some (especially old) architectures could avoid the overhead by having self-modifying machine code; so that the initialization-test is actually removed after the first time. (Doing it on a modern multi-thread architecture would be challenging.)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is almost certainly slightly slower. Most of the time it will however not matter and the cost will be outweighted by the "logic and style" benefit.

Technically, a function-local static variable is the same as a global variable. Only just that its name is *not* globally known (which is a good thing), and its initialization is guaranteed to happen not only at an exactly specified time, but also only once, and threadsafe.

This means that a function-local static variable *must* know whether initialization has happened, and thus needs at least one extra memory access and one conditional jump that the global (in principle) doesn't need. An implemenation *may* do someting similar for globals, but it *needs not* (and usually doesn't).

Chances are good that the jump is predicted correctly in all cases but two. The first two calls are highly likely to be predicted wrong (usually jumps are by default assumed to be taken rather than not, wrong assumption on first call, and subsequent jumps are assumed to take the same path as the last one, again wrong). After that, you should be good to go, near 100% correct prediction.
But even a correctly predicted jump isn't free (the CPU can still only start a given number of instructions every cycle, even assuming they take zero time to complete), but it's not much. If the memory latency, which may be a couple of hundred cycles in the worst case can be successfully hidden, the cost *almost* disappears in pipelining. Also, every access fetches an extra cacheline that wouldn't otherwise be needed (the has-been-initialized flag likely isn't stored in the same cache line as the data). Thus, you have slightly worse L1 performance (L2 should be big enough so you can say "yeah, so what").

It also needs to actually perform something *once and threadsafe* that the global (in principle) doesn't have to do, at least not in a way that you see. An implementation can do something different, but most just initialize globals before `main` is entered, and not rarely most of it is done with a `memset` or implicitly because the variable is stored in a segment that is zeroed anyway.
Your static variable *must* be initialized when the initialization code is executed, and it must happen in a threadsafe manner. Depending on how much your implementation sucks this can be quite expensive. I decided to forfeit on the thread safety feature and always compile with `fno-threadsafe-statics` (even if this isn't standard-compliant) after discovering that GCC (which is otherwise an OK allround compiler) would actually lock a mutex for every static initialization.

Answer (score 2):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

> **Deferred dynamic initialization**
>   It is implementation-defined whether dynamic initialization happens-before the first statement of the main function (for statics) or the initial function of the thread (for thread-locals), or deferred to happen after.
>
> If the initialization of a non-inline variable (since C++17) is deferred to happen after the first statement of main/thread function, it happens before the first odr-use of any variable with static/thread storage duration defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

So similar check **may** have to be done also for global variables.

so `f()` is not necessary *"slower"* than `g()`.

Comment: GCC and clang don't compile that way, though.  Do any compilers do that?  I've never heard of it until seeing this mention of the theoretical possibility.  The C++ standard leaves open as many implementation options as possible, even ones that would be clearly worse on all "normal" CPUs / implementations.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I think it (might) happens with DLL/.so loading actually.

Comment: Normal dynamic linking is done before execution reaches the top of `main`.  ISO C++ doesn't really define dynamically loading more code at run-time via things like `dlopen`, but yes, on platforms that do define that, running static initializers after loading a new shared library but before there's any possibility to call into it would be an example of that ISO C++ rule in action.

Comment: But no, there aren't "similar checks" in each function that uses a global when compiling a shared lib (e.g. with `gcc -fPIC`); `dlopen` doesn't return until after it's done calling static constructors in the shared lib (the metadata in the .so has the info it needs to find an init function pointer or table of function pointers in the shared library).  Only after that point can you call `dlsym` to get a function pointer to call into the shared library.  The Windows DLL equivalent works more or less the same, not letting you get a function pointer until the library's globals are initted AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

`g()` is not thread-safe, and is susceptible to all sorts of ordering problems. Safety is going to come at a price. There are several ways to pay it:

`f()`, the Meyer's Singleton, pays the price on every access. If accessed frequently or accessed during a performance-sensitive section of your code, then it does make sense to avoid `f()`. Your processor presumably has a finite number of circuits it can devote to branch prediction, and you are being forced to read an atomic variable before the branch anyway. It is a tall price to continually pay for just ensuring that the initialization happened only once.

`h()`, described below, works very much like `g()` with an extra indirection, but assumes that `h_init()` gets called exactly once at the beginning of execution. Preferably, you would define a subroutine that gets called as the line of `main()`; that calls every function like `h_init()`, with an absolute ordering. Hopefully, these objects do not need to be destructed.

Alternatively, if you use GCC, you can annotate `h_init()` with `__attribute__((constructor))`. I prefer the explicitness of the static init subroutine though.

```
A * h_global = nullptr;
void h_init() { h_global = new A { }; }
A const& h() { return *h_global; }
```

`h2()` is just like `h()`, minus the extra indirection:

```
alignas(alignof(A)) char h2_global [sizeof(A)] = { };
void h2_init() { new (std::begin(h2_global)) A { }; }
A const& h2() { return * reinterpret_cast <A const *> (std::cbegin(h2_global)); }
```

Comment: given that `g()` accesses `global` that is constructed before `main()` is called, I wouldn't worry too much about its thread safety

Comment: @DevNull There is also the ordering problem: if nontrivial static object `x` is depended upon to initialize some other static object `y` in a different translation unit, and `y` gets initialized first, `y` may be initialized with a bogus value.

Comment: true, but this can be worked around with nifty counters.

Comment: @DevNull Disagree, that trick looks like a disaster waiting to happen. If you already have a specific ordering, you should just make that explicit.